# Generating sourcemaps when minifying with the ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bundle, minify, source-maps

Is there a way to generate sourcemaps for the scripts minified by the optimization framework?

I have found a lot of resources talking about Web Essetials, but that oly generates the min and map files, at compiletime. The scripts that I need to bundle comes from different sources, so I cannot rely on functionality of vs.net.

Same problem is addressed in this question: [Reconciling ASP.NET script bundles and source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431036/reconciling-asp-net-script-bundles-and-source-maps)

Comment: @FuriousFolder. I found the other post AFTER i posted this one. Please check the edit history, before downvoting.

I provided the link to the other question to help other people, who, like me, didn't find that other post.

Comment: This question has upvotes, which means it was helpful for at least some other people, so I don't see the need to close it. I don't know what it is you expected me to answer.

Comment: My issue is that I flagged this as a dupe, and the mods decided it wasn't. Ok. Fine. So I add a comment, asking you to post an answer. You decide not to, citing the utility of the question along with the fact that it's a duplicate. Seems to me you can't both have a question that IS a duplicate and not be flagged, and also NOT  a duplicate without an answer.

Comment: So does that linked question actually tell you what you want to know? Or is there something else you're trying to ask? Could you please clarify what, if anything, you still want to know?

Comment: @Furious Folder. I still don't know what it is you expected me to answer.

Comment: @johnsharpe. My question is over a year old and I found other solutions to the actual problem. The linked question didn't tell me what to know at the time I edited my question, but as I found another solution, I didn't really check up on it.

If the mods deems this question a douplicate, go right ahead and delete it. :-)

Comment: Duplicate != deleted. It means the answer is marked as a duplicate so other duplicates link to it and vice versa.