# Debugging JavaScript with source maps in IE7, IE8, IE9 and IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, source-maps

I didn't find a way to debug using source maps in Internet Explorer < 11.

Does visual studio support debugging with JavaScript source maps?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with IE7 and IE8. It doesn't seem to know about source maps. Is there some extension, or anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reconciling ASP.NET script bundles and source maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431036/reconciling-asp-net-script-bundles-and-source-maps)

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think you're going to struggle here. Visual Studio doesn't support it, because it leaves it to IE11's dev tools. Older IE versions don't get a look in.

In my opinion, the closest you're going to get is using IE11's compatibility modes to emulate the older IE versions rather than (or as well as) using real copies of the old IE versions.

I know as well as anyone that compatibility mode is not a perfect emulation, but I don't see any other way to do what you're asking.

The only other option I can offer you is to deploy your JavaScript in a non-minified form, at least for those older browsers while you're trying to debug them.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Visual Studio does support JavaScript source maps with IE7 upwards.

You have to use its own debugger.