# ASP.NET Bundles SourceMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, source-maps

I am enabling bundle optimization in asp.net for my javascript and css files, how can I enabled SourceMap generation? should I move to other minifer?

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431036/reconciling-asp-net-script-bundles-and-source-maps

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the script bundling has support yet.  You can try web essentials which does: http://vswebessentials.com/

Comment: I want to be built in my build and deployment, If there is any open source/nuget package that I can use - it will be OK.

Comment: Is this still the case?